# How to synchronize Gradle with project in Android studio 0.8.9?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am very new to android studio.I have installed android studio and gradle in my system. I am not able to sync gradle with my project, i keep on getting this message "Error:Cause: invalid END header (bad central directory offset)" and i am not able to download android targeted versions in SDK, downloading fails showing error message "Download interrupted: bad record MAC".
i am stuck with this for 2 days.i am pleased to get any ideas from anyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
file->Invalidedata Caches/Restart
```